# Unable to write the entries in /etc/fstab

Tags: linux, swap, ansible

I am using below playbook to write the entries in `/etc/fstab` & to create swap file:

```
---

- name: Configure SWAP
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  become_user: root

  tasks:
    - name: Configuring a SWAP
      command: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - mkswap -f "{{ ebs_swap }}"
        - echo "UUID=$(blkid -s UUID -o value {{ ebs_swap }})   swap    swap   defaults  0   0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
        - swapon -a
```

We are running it using below command:
`ansible-playbook mount.yml -e "ebs_swap=/dev/xvdj"`

Can any one tell me why am i unable to get the entry in `/etc/fstab` & when i am trying to run above commands its getting success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Ansible's `command` module which expects standalone binaries, but the `echo...` line needs to be fed to a shell to interpret it. Replace `command:` with `shell:` and your playbook should then work.

You can also safely remove 'sudo' from your command since the command will be executing as root...

...but to achieve that you may need to specify the `--ask-become-pass` flag (short form `-K`) to your `ansible-playbook` command, thus,

```
ansible-playbook mount.yml -K -e "ebs_swap=/dev/xvdj"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved above as below:

```
---

- name: Configure SWAP
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  become_user: root

  tasks:
    - name: Dispaly swap uuid & store in variable
      command: blkid -s UUID -o value {{ ebs_swap }}
      register: uuid_swap

    - name: Adding arguments as CIS benchmark to /etc/fstab file
      blockinfile:
       path: /etc/fstab
       state: present
       block: |
          UUID={{ uuid_swap.stdout }}   swap      swap defaults              0   0
```